# "Broken my duck"? Is this a common idiom/phrase?

Tags: etymology, phrases, idioms

I steal this phrase from a comment on Meta Stack Overflow:

> yep, I think **I've broken my duck** or so to speak :) – Kev♦ 51 mins ago

The context is one of having been basically broken into a particular fold, or going through a rite of passage - Kev has symbolically become a true moderator because he has gotten a Meta thread about his actions.

But the phrase is... unusual, to be soft about it. You don't break open ducks, or really most animals at all you don't break. Is this a common idiom? If so, what in hejudas inspired such a phrasing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This might help, it's a fairly common'ish phrase in the UK.

In summary it's a cricket related term. In cricket a ["Duck"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_%28cricket%29) is where a player has been dismissed from play without scoring a point. "Breaking one's duck" is the occasion where a you break a run of ducks.

> [breaking your duck - boards.ie](http://www.boards.ie/vbulletin/showpost.php?p=53686235&postcount=3)

Outside of cricket the term is often used to describe having done something for the first time.

Comment: A good answer should stand on its own. Can you summarize the relevant portion of the linked post?

Comment: Link rot happens. Please post a summary of the information found at your link, in case it goes the way of all things. Thanks!

Comment: @mmyers: Jinx!!

Comment: @Martha: Jinx? I had you beat by a good minute and a half.

Comment: @mmyers, Before my edit, the gap was less than a minute, and whoever says "Jinx" first wins the jinx. :)

Comment: @Martha: I don't think editing changes the timestamp. And what happens if both people say "Jinx" at the same time? Meta-jinx?

Comment: @mmyers: yup, meta-jinx. But you're right about the timestamp not changing, so I'll let you off the hook about the jinx. This time.

Comment: @Kev - surely the batsman "breaks his duck" as soon as he scores the first run *in this game* (or possibly innings) rather than a first run after a series of games where he scores a duck? (A minor point I know!)

Comment: @AAT - you're probably right, I was just explaining the origin of the term, I also don't pretend to know much about cricket either. Like all things, its day to day use probably isn't as precise as it's original use.

Comment: But why _duck_? Can you explain that in your answer?

Comment: @Mitch - that would be another question. The post wasn't about why they call it a "Duck", it was *"Broken my duck”? Is this a common idiom/phrase?"*. I've already explained what a "Duck" is. The linked wikipedia does as good an explanation of ***why*** it's called a "Duck" as I could ever do.

Comment: @Kev: If all you're doing is giving a link then that is not a good answer here. You should at least summarize what you've read elsewhere (but of course keep the link for more details).

Comment: @Mitch - I've already explained **what** a Duck is, there is no need for me to explain **why** it's called a duck because that is **not** what the question was about. What next, explain why Cricket is called cricket or what a run is and why it's called that? Feel free to edit this into my answer if it makes you happier.

Answer (score 6):

To break one's duck means the person has done something for the first time. The phrase comes not from duck as an animal, but from a [duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_%28cricket%29) in cricket, which is *a batsman's dismissal for a score of zero.* Therefore, when one breaks his duck, they score the first point.