# Is “what in hejudas?” a common idiom or phrase?

Tags: etymology, phrases, is-it-a-word, minced-oaths

I noticed the following phrase used in [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/broken-my-duck-is-this-a-common-idiom-phrase):

> Is this a common idiom? If so, **what in hejudas** inspired such a phrasing?

Obviously, this is similar to the phrases “what in hell” or “what on earth”.  Does it have its own etymology?  Does it relate to [Judas Iscariot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot) somehow?

Is this a common idiom? If so, what in hejudas inspired such a phrasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, *hejudas* isn’t a real word and as such isn’t a common phrase on its own. The version I used in that post is based off a random nonce-exclamation I made when I was really young and needed to express a great sense of confusion. I kept that usage, since it, like a couple other consistent nonsense words I coined from my youth, doubled as an excellent way to avoid speaking what is often considered profanity.

It replicates the usage of *hell* specifically as an intensifier for expressing perplexity. Generally as a “What the hejudas” kind of deal, but I’ve never constrained myself to following grammar rules when I’m trying to express befuddlement.

In that sense, it’s a mirror of the more common “what the hell” phrase.

No, it has nothing to do with Judas.

Comment: It sounds like an amalgam of hell/Jesus in order to avoid cursing...similar to "heck" or "jeez" or "Godfrey Daniels".