# What is the etymology of the names for the number 0 in English

Tags: meaning, etymology

I was always wondering what is the etymology of the different names of number 0 .In sports like tennis, cricket, and football, the number **0** has the very specialized names "**love**", "**duck**", and "**nil**".

Comment: vaguely related: [I've broken my duck](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/26809/broken-my-duck-is-this-a-common-idiom-phrase)

Comment: another: [why "love" in tennis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733)

Comment: Vote to close as overly broad; you're asking either 3 different questions, at least some of which are general reference, or asking an open question for various terms that we will come up with.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do they say "love fifteen," in tennis?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20733/why-do-they-say-love-fifteen-in-tennis)

Comment: This is only the beginning... there is also the term [zilch](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zilch) and [zip](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=zip&allowed_in_frame=0) and [nada](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nada&searchmode=none). Then there is the word [bupkis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bupkis). Just how many different words for nothing _are_ there...? (Here's [one list](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wikisaurus:nothing).)

Comment: Voted to close as worded. There might be a good question lurking in here ... but I can't find it. Why zero gets more synonyms than one, why goose vs duck, whether these spread from sport to sport or outside of sports ... something in that direction might help improve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Love](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=love&searchmode=none) in tennis comes from the notion *playing for love*, i.e. *for nothing*.

Since [nil](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=nil&searchmode=none) means *nothing*, it's easy to understand why it is used to denote the score. What is not explained, however, is how it came to be used on sports occasions.

As for [duck](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duck), one of its meanings is *to lose a trick by deliberately playing lower than one's opponent*, hence gaining zero points.

Comment: +1. The OED says ‘duck' is a shortened form of 'duck’s egg', but gives no further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of *duck* in cricket is that it comes from 'duck's egg'.  The scorer starts with a 0 (or circle, or egg) against each player, because he starts with no runs.  When the batsman scores his first run, he 'breaks his duck' because the first run is put either against or through the 0  If he doesn't he is 'out for a duck's egg', or a duck for short:  a 'golden duck' if out first ball.
(I have no references for this, but if you think the wordplay is too weak and contrived to catch on, you only have to look at the live text on the BBC website for the current Tests to see that this is rapier wit by comparison: cricket spectators have a lot of time to chat.)

Comment: I came across this explanation myself and it is certainly valid for cricket. It is a folk belief that the term [duck's egg](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Duck+(cricket)) comes from the shape of number 0 being similar in shape to that of a duck's egg.

Comment: In America, the term ['goose egg'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/goose+egg) is also used for the score '0'.

Answer (score 1):

Although there isn't agreement on the subject, an alternative origin for the term "love" in tennis is L'oeuf, or (the) egg, in French.

The use of egg to mean the number 0, is due to the fact that the shape of the numeral is similar to the shape of the object.

Answer (score 0):

*Null* (and I would presume *nil*) come from Latin *nullus* or none. *Zero* and *null* are technically not the same thing in computer science, but in Norwegian they seem to be interchangeable. I remember them using *null* to mean *zero*.